# Alternative to copyTo function

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I am using Python3 with MongoDB.

I need to copy the contents of collection A to collection B.

I have tried `A.copyTo(B)` without success.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: for now , I have first queried all and looped through and inserted to other collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to clone a collection is to use the [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/aggregation/) method with a single `out`stage. For example:

```
A.aggregate([{"$out":"B"}])
```

will clone all the items in the collection `A` to a new collection `B`.